# Grouping issue with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I have the following data:

```
SUM_OF_ALL_PUSHES  |   USER_LOGIN  |   COMPONENT_NAME  | ROW_LST_UPD_TS
-------------------|---------------|-------------------|-------------------------
61                 |   DOMAIN\abc  |   Component A     | 22/02/12 12:58:26.325 PM
14                 |   DOMAIN\xyz  |   Component B     | 22/02/12 05:20:52.565 PM
17                 |   DOMAIN\xyz  |   Component A     | 22/02/12 05:21:58.045 PM
34                 |   DOMAIN\abc  |   Component A     | 22/02/12 05:44:20.274 PM
38                 |   DOMAIN\abc  |   Component A     | 22/02/12 06:28:41.465 PM
```

I'm deriving the the data using the following:

```
SELECT SUM(Q.SUM_OF_ALL_PUSHES) AS SUM_OF_ALL_PUSHES, Q.USER_LOGIN, Q.COMPONENT_NAME, Q.ROW_LST_UPD_TS FROM( SELECT                
    SUM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTR(EVENT_MSG, INSTR(EVENT_MSG, ' ', 1,1), INSTR(EVENT_MSG, ' ', 1,1)) , '[0-9]+')) AS "SUM_OF_ALL_PUSHES", 
    USER_LOGIN,
    COMPONENT_NAME, 
    EVENT_MSG, 
    ROW_LST_UPD_TS
FROM EVENT_MGT.EVENT_LOG
WHERE
ROW_LST_UPD_TS BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1/86400
AND SUBSTR(EVENT_MSG,1 ,INSTR(EVENT_MSG, 'd', 1,1)) = 'Received'
GROUP BY 
    USER_LOGIN, 
    COMPONENT_NAME, 
    EVENT_MSG, 
    ROW_LST_UPD_TS) Q
GROUP BY COMPONENT_NAME, USER_LOGIN, ROW_LST_UPD_TS 
ORDER BY ROW_LST_UPD_TS ASC
```

The issue is that I need to sum the numbers for each user by component. So in the results set above, I need to aggregate columns 1, 4 and 5 and add up the values for SUM_OF_ALL_PUSHES since the records each have user abc, and Component A.

So in summary, I need to remove the data duplication in the other columns, and sum the values in the first column based on user and component. So the result set should look like this:

```
SUM_OF_ALL_PUSHES  |   USER_LOGIN  |   COMPONENT_NAME  | ROW_LST_UPD_TS
-------------------|---------------|-------------------|-------------------------
133                |   DOMAIN\abc  |   Component A     | 22/02/12 12:58:26.325 PM
14                 |   DOMAIN\xyz  |   Component B     | 22/02/12 05:20:52.565 PM
17                 |   DOMAIN\xyz  |   Component A     | 22/02/12 05:21:58.045 PM
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you don't want to group by the timestamp, but instead apply an aggregate function (I'm guessing `MAX`) to it.

```
SELECT SUM(Q.SUM_OF_ALL_PUSHES) AS SUM_OF_ALL_PUSHES, Q.USER_LOGIN, Q.COMPONENT_NAME, MAX(Q.ROW_LST_UPD_TS) FROM( SELECT                
    SUM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTR(EVENT_MSG, INSTR(EVENT_MSG, ' ', 1,1), INSTR(EVENT_MSG, ' ', 1,1)) , '[0-9]+')) AS "SUM_OF_ALL_PUSHES", 
    USER_LOGIN,
    COMPONENT_NAME, 
    EVENT_MSG, 
    ROW_LST_UPD_TS
FROM EVENT_MGT.EVENT_LOG
WHERE
ROW_LST_UPD_TS BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1/86400
AND SUBSTR(EVENT_MSG,1 ,INSTR(EVENT_MSG, 'd', 1,1)) = 'Received'
GROUP BY 
    USER_LOGIN, 
    COMPONENT_NAME, 
    EVENT_MSG, 
    ROW_LST_UPD_TS) Q
GROUP BY COMPONENT_NAME, USER_LOGIN 
ORDER BY MAX(Q.ROW_LST_UPD_TS) ASC
```

Comment: I never would have thought of using Max, but it does exactly what I want. Thanks so much for this. I don't understand why it works, however. The MAX function returns the maximum value of an expression. So how does taking the maximum value of the date aggregate the records like this? Please explain if you have a moment. Thanks!

Comment: You don't want to group by `ROW_LST_UPD_TS`, since you don't want a separate row for each unique value of that column.  Therefore you need to remove it from the `GROUP BY` clause; but in a grouping query, each expression in the select list must either be a grouping column or be a group function.  So you need to apply a group function to this column to make the query work.  `MAX` just happens to be the group function that gives the result you seemed to want.